# Depth of infinite direct sum

Tags: commutative-algebra, infinity

Let $R$ is a local ring, from the depth lemma, we can get $\operatorname{depth}(R\oplus\dotsb\oplus R)=\operatorname{depth}(R)$, here the direct sum is finite, how about the infinite case?

By the intuition, at least for the countable $R$, the result is also $\operatorname{depth}(R)$, but we have depth $R[x]=\operatorname{depth}(R)+1$, any difference between the $R[x]$ and the countable direct sum of $R$?

Comment: As an $R$-module, $R[x]$ is just a countable direct sum of copies of $R$. So is $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ for that matter. I'm not really sure what your question is

Comment: You also seem to be confusing the depth of $R[x]$ as a ring, versus its depth as an $R$-module. As an $R$-module, $\text{depth}(R[x]) = \text{depth}(R)$ (and also, by convention, the depth of a ring is only referred to when the ring is local, which $R[x]$ is not)

Comment: Oh, thanks. My main question is that what is the depth of infinite direct sum of R, if it is depth(R), how to prove?

Comment: How define the depth of module which is not finitely generated?

Comment: @user121097: I took it to mean the sup of the lengths of regular $M$-sequences. It is true that typically depth is only defined for finitely generated modules - perhaps this point should indeed be emphasized.

Comment: Oh, yes, finitely generated modules is the condition, but here R[x] do not look bad. Thanks for the following answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be a local ring. If $M$ is faithfully flat over $R$, then $\text{depth}_R(M) = \text{depth}(R)$, since for any $R$-ideal $I$ and any $x \in R$,

$$0 \to R/I \xrightarrow{x} R/I \to R/(I, x) \to 0$$

is exact iff

$$0 \to M/IM \xrightarrow{x} M/IM \to M/(I, x)M \to 0$$

is exact, so a sequence of elements $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is regular on $R$ iff it is regular on $M$ (note that the first map gives weak regularity, and the second map improves this to full regularity).